# jquery( tr_selector ) is removing the style values from the nested td's

Tags: jquery

I have a table:

```
<table>
  <tr data-my_group = 'A'>
    <td style                 = 'blah:blah;' 
        data-some_custom_prop = 'purple' >
    ...
```

If I do this:

```
var this_row = jQuery("[data-my_group = 'A']"):eq(0) ;
console.log( this_row ) ; // for firebug
```

... and then using firebug drill down to the cell in question, I see:

- `style= "                              "`
- `data-some_custom_prop = 'purple'`

The style's value is lost (and it has been turned into white space).

This has real implications, as I am supplying `this_row` as an argument to an `insertAfter` method ... but since the `<td>` has lost its style, the resulting display is wrong.

Comment: Please supply some code along with making your question more clear.

Comment: I re-wrote the post ... hopefully it should be clearer now ... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/nN6Pv/ shows that cloning and appending the rows retains all style data.

```
var this_row = $("[data-my_group = 'A']").eq(0) ;
var new_row = $(this_row).clone();
$('table').append(new_row);
console.log( this_row ) ; // returns [object Object] as it should
```

Comment: I should really delete this question ... your response correctly indicated that I was looking in the wrong place ... thanks.

Comment: If it helped you it shouldn't be deleted.